# Is there a term for functions starting with the "Is" prefix?

Tags: coding-standards, conventions

There are a number of functions of a kind; returning a boolean, and the name always starts with the "Is" prefix.

e.g. `IsAlive()`, `IsDead()`, `IsKeyPressed()`, `IsKeyReleased()`, etc.

How do we categorize these kind of functions? Is there a vocabulary for that?

Comment: Maybe a **predicate**?

Comment: Those functions are certainly predicates. Though that is independent of that naming-convention being used or not. In C++ for example, most predicates are unnamed lambdas, or at least don't use any prefix for the name. Also, they mostly don't return a boolean, but something convertible to boolean.

Comment: @Giorgio - that's exactly right. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Giorgio that would be a great answer, which would deserve an upvote if it provided with an explanation

Comment: I wonder if "Can" and "Has" methods [or getter-only properties in some languages] fall into the same category?  `CanExecute`, `HasValue`

Comment: @Nick Alexeev Yes. As we all know, those are one very widely commonly used pattern. I'm looking for this concept because I thought it could be an important feature in software design. Basically it is like an exported function (a public method in OO) that can tell a state of something, whether it's true or false. It usually comes with the "Is" prefix. But we can also use "Can" or "Has" replacing "IsAbleTo" or "IsAvailable", etc.

Comment: Does there need to be a term for that?  They're functions that return Booleans, nothing more.  Booleans that reflect state aren't any different than numbers that reflect state (e.g., `length()` or `area()`)  Looking at them as a design feature is a lot like falling into the design-patterns-as-building-blocks trap.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term [Predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) - in the context of mathematical logic, and mentioned in a comment by @Giorgio - describes all kinds of boolean valued functions, not just functions starting with the prefix `Is`. Note this term is to some degree ambigous, it has [several meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate), boolean valued functions is just one of them.

As you noticed, it is a common naming convention in programming to give boolean functions a prefix like `Is`, `Can`, or `Has`, like mentioned in [this SO older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370840/naming-conventions-what-to-name-a-method-that-returns-a-boolean). I doubt, however, there is a special category for predicates starting with the prefix `Is`, except the category *"predicates starting with the prefix `Is`"*.

Comment: In the context of programming, conversions come into it, so functions which are not actually boolean-valued, but whose return-values are convertible to boolean, can also be predicates.

Comment: @Deduplicator: yes, and even in mathematical logic the term is to some degree ambigous.

Comment: I've never heard this used but Existential Predicates sounds better than "predicates starting with the prefix Is" ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such vocabulary for using this kind of functions. You can simply use it without **Is** prefix also. But as per coding standard you should use that prefix in your code as it will help you in future as well as other other developers to understand the code better. As generally we understand like is or has prefixed function names means they always return boolean. So, it can be helped to understand easily.

Suppose you are not using **is / has** prefix then in such a case any developer has to check that which type of data will be returned by the function and go through the return statement. So I suggest that you should use **is / has** as a prefix.